# How to specify a Dockerfile without passing it inline or hosted on a git server

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

In Openshift Origin, I need to build and deploy from a Dockerfile in my local filesystem. It isn't hosted on a git server. Anybody know how I can specify that in the URI?

```
source:
  git:
    ref: master
    uri: https://github.com/some/project
  type: Git
strategy:
  dockerStrategy:
    from:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      name: java-centos:oracle-8-jdk
  type: Docker
```

Also, I'm aware of passing the Dockerfile inline, but I don't want to do that. I want to be able to indicate where the Dockerfile is located in the filesystem.

I also tried:

```
oc new-app --name blog --strategy=docker C:\my\folder\containing\Dockerfile
```

Ted

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
oc new-build --name blog --strategy=docker --binary
```

This will create a build configuration for a binary input build, but nothing else.

Each time you want to run a build, you would run:

```
oc start-build blog --from-dir .
```

Run this in the directory where the `Dockerfile` and other files are located.

Once the build has completed the first time, you can then run:

```
oc new-app --image-stream blog --name blog
```

to create a deployment for the application.

If it was a web application and you want to make it publicly access, you can then run:

```
oc expose svc/blog
```